# What is wrong with my PDF after managing to put them to .ZIP and download successfully

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, jszip

I successfully downloaded .zip file which contains downloaded pdfs. My problem is when i extract it and open it, pdfs have some weird letters. It's my first time doing such thing so i'm somehow stuck and i don't know what might cause this problem. I get status 200 in postman and message "written" in terminal from console.log. Here's a screenshot of my code, and pdf also. If anyone knows, please help, i've been trying for a few days :/

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiQpB.png)
[pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApZwM.png)

[pdf properties 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b11tN.png)

[pdf properties 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crFEi.png)

Answer (score 1):

Those pdf files may be referencing fonts that are not available on the viewing device. Try downloading them individually and see if you get the same results.
Update - The fonts all check out. Nothing exotic.

The only server side / transport issue that comes to mind is accessing a binary file in text mode but the correct content-type should preclude anything like that.

PDFs are already compressed, zip files only add value for batch download.

The symptom that the pdf properties are corrupted points to a pdf writer rendering bug. Some ways to confirm that hypothesis are to:

- Lint the pdf file to ensure it is whole.
- Try viewing it in a multitude of readers.
- Submit to VirusTotal for malware evaluation.

Comment: Check for Embedded Fonts
To check whether the fonts are all embedded in your PDF file or not:

Open your PDF file
Click File> Document Properties
Click on the Fonts Tab to display the list of all fonts
All fonts are either Type 1 or TrueType fonts
All fonts should show as “Embedded Subset”

Comment: Thank you, i'll check it out,i thought it might be something related to letters/formats although im still not quite sure. Thank you so much man :D

Comment: I added screenshots pdf properties 1 and 2 so you can see it. I tried downloading just a single one,but i got the same outcome.